# Convert Oracle Hierarchical Query To SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am doing a data migration from Oracle to Sql Server 2008. I have come across a view that has the following query:

```
 SELECT limit_phrase, LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(res_val,','))
        KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS concat_limit

   FROM   ( SELECT limit_phrase
          , SUBSTR(UPPER(RESULT_VALUE),1,INSTR(RESULT_VALUE,'-')-1) as res_val
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY limit_phrase ORDER BY SUBSTR(UPPER(RESULT_VALUE),1,INSTR(RESULT_VALUE,'-')-1)) AS curr
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY limit_phrase ORDER BY SUBSTR(UPPER(RESULT_VALUE),1,INSTR(RESULT_VALUE,'-')-1)) -1 AS prev
            FROM   limit_phrase_entry lpe, limit_phrase_header lph
            WHERE lpe.limit_phrase = lph.[IDENTITY]
            AND lpe.comparison = 'P')

   GROUP BY limit_phrase
   CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND limit_phrase = PRIOR limit_phrase
   START WITH curr = 1;
```

As you can see there are some ORACLE functions and mnemonics that do not translate to SQL Server. For example, the hierarchical query: START WITH....connect by;  OVER (PARTITION BY...;  KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr)
How would one go about converting the SELECT statement into a SQL Server statement?